# Poem about a gross but beautiful urban garden, possibly by Millay

Tags: identification-request, poetry, edna-st-vincent-millay

I have a dim but vivid memory of a poem, 95% sure it was by Edna St. Vincent Millay, about an urban garden alive with beauty despite everything that’s gross about it. Toads, fungus, etc. are the vibe. It is NOT “[City Trees](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/59167/59167-h/59167-h.htm#p_40)” but very much in that vein. I also remember longer lines, e.g. more like the line-lengths of “[Recuerdo](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/59167/59167-h/59167-h.htm#p_21)” than “[Daphne](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/59167/59167-h/59167-h.htm#p_30)”.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is the sonnet ‘**Still will I harvest beauty where it grows**’ (1920) by Edna St Vincent Millay:

> Still will I harvest beauty where it grows:
> In coloured fungus and the spotted fog
> Surprised on foods forgotten; in ditch and bog
> Filmed brilliant with irregular rainbows
> Of rust and oil, where half a city throws
> Its empty tins; and in some spongy log
> Whence headlong leaps the oozy emerald frog….
> And a black pupil in the green scum shows.
> Her the inhabiter of divers places
> Surmising at all doors, I push them all.
> Oh, you that fearful of a creaking hinge
> Turn back forevermore with craven faces,
> I tell you Beauty bears an ultra fringe
> Unguessed of you upon her gossamer shawl!
>
> <sub>Edna St Vincent Millay (1923). [*The Harp-Weaver and Other Poems*, p. 72](https://archive.org/details/harpweaverotherp01mill/page/72/mode/2up). London: Harper & Brothers.</sub>